# Error in copy-paste-transpose vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 years worth of data with each year having 4 quarters. Each of this has bank names within. I wrote a vba code to copy all data, and paste transpose into a newly created worksheet at the end of the workbook. The code ran fine.

However, it seems that only banks that begin with the letter "A" was copied. The rest was not. I have no idea why.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim thiswb As Workbook, datawb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim datafolder As String
    Dim cell As Range, datawblist As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
    i = 2
    'Have the 40 file names in sheet2 of this workbook in cells A1:A40
    Set datawblist = thiswb.Sheets("command").Range("A45:A61")
    datafolder = "C:\Users\bryan\Desktop\Y4S1\Money and Banking\Empirical\QuarterSheets\2007q1\" 'change this to your directory they're in

    For Each cell In datawblist
        Set datawb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=datafolder & cell & ".csv", ReadOnly:=True)
        Set ws = thiswb.Sheets.Add(After:=thiswb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        datawb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, _
                    Transpose:=True
        datawb.Close savechanges:=False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you reduce the code to deal with only one such imported sheet, that still shows the problem, and then share what is in that sheet, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: I realised that the code worked for csv. But once I saved as xls, all names beyond letter A disappears. Is there a reason?

Comment: What do you mean with "all names beyond letter A"? Are you speaking of names as defined in Excel, or are names values in cells, or are names file names? Can you give example of what you get and what you expected to get?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is solved. CSV just could store more data, whereas after I save as XLS, all the data that exceeds disappears

Comment: How many rows/columns are we talking about?

Comment: 256 columns, 65000 rows.

Comment: 65000 is near the limit for XLS. Try saving in the newer Excel format XLSX.